# Loading images from mobile devices javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mobile

I am developing a mobile/web friendly web application. In that tapping on a mobile icon in a page should list the images from mobile device. How this can be achieved using javascript/jquery? This should work on all devices.

Thanks,

Comment: Mobile browser does not have access to the file system...I doubt you are asking about opening browse prompt which opens when one tries to upload files...Clarify...

Comment: I need to list the selected images from mobile device in the page. It is not regarding upload.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, browser can not access files from the device. Forget mobile..Could you display files from your PC in browser...?

Comment: That I need to search next.

Comment: If you are looking for `D:\ ` then in mobile, use `file:\\\sdcard`.....

Comment: could you please post sample JS code to use this??

Comment: There is nothing about js code...I am not sure how will you know the path of the image which resides in the device of the end user...Type `file:///sdcard` in your mobile and check..